# useState not setting variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am confused why `useState` is not setting the variable from its argument, `props`.

The fragment is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const FormContainer = (props) => {
  console.log('[FormContainer props]', props);   // line 7
  const [prevState, setPrevState] = useState(props);
  console.log('[FormContainer]', prevState);     // line 9
```

`props` contains an object but the hook is not setting `prevState`. It is `undefined`. Why?

Calling code. The first component presents a list. When a row in the list (grid) is clicked, this component gets the data and sends it as an argument to the second component, FormContainer.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from './VehicleList';
import VehicleForm from '../FormContainer';

class Vehicles extends Component {
  state = {};

...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        {this.state && this.state.vehicleList && (
          <Table vehicleList={this.state.vehicleList} clicked={this.vehicleSelectedHandler} />
        )}
        {console.log('[Vehicles render selectedVehicle]', this.state.selectedVehicle)}
        <VehicleForm vehicle={this.state.selectedVehicle} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

From the debugger:

[image: Firefox dev tools]

Comment: Why do you need `useState` in `FormContainer`? How do you use `prevState`? Please add all relevant code. You probaly need some form of `useEffect` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: The calling code fetches a vehicle object via API call and passes it to the form. I want the form to pass back the edited data for posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` takes the default value as its argument. It will be set only on the first render and will not update when `props` change. You should call `setPrevState` to update the values.

`useState` is used to access the current state. If you need something for previous props or previous state take a look at the [FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)

It is not a good idea to implement this with hooks. Vehicle state and updating should be inside `Vehicles` component. There is no need for `useState` inside a class. `VehicleForm` should be a stateless component and should receive a callback to update the vehicle.

It would be hard to track changes and handle updates in a generic `FormContainer` based on the whole `props` object.

Comment: It's not getting set in the original call. Are you suggesting creating the hook and immediately calling the second argument, setPrevState? I should have not named it prev.

Comment: @user2443507 the code `this.state.selectedVehicle` suggests that nothing is selected during 1st render, only AFTER some user interaction => you need to explicitly call the setter, not rely on the default value from the first render

Comment: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
    ▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
    FormContainer
    src/containers/FormContainer.js:9
       6 | const FormContainer = (props) => {
       7 |   console.log('[FormContainer props]', props);
       8 |   const [prevState, setPrevState] = useState();
    >  9 |   setPrevState(props);

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should probably change your approach or use some existing library to handle forms.